# Forced damped harmonic motion, angular frequency at which amplitude is maximum. differentiation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, oscillators, resonance

$$A_0 = \frac{(F_0/m)}{\sqrt{(\omega_0^2-\omega_d^2)^2+b^2\omega_d^2/m^2}}$$

How would I differentiate this with respect to the driven angular frequency (equating to zero) in order to obtain the max value of the amplitude in terms of these components?

Comment: How do you differentiate *any* function with respect to its variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator doesn't depend on the frequency, so you just want to minimize the denominator. That's the same as minimizing the square of the denominator. Now it should be simple!

Comment: AH, thank you very much.. now im wondering why this bothered so much.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions like this. It's better to ask the OP to improve the quality. Answering these questions encourages more of them.